# Backbone.js- Scope of 'this' in a Model method

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have a problem with the scope of 'this' when defining a Backbone model.
In the function updateGeoLocation  I'm calling an anonymous function that handles the update of the location and placement of the marker.

The problem is that when inside the anonymous function 'this' refer to the window instead of the model.
I tried to add this to my init function but it still doesn't solve the problem:

```
 _.bindAll(this , 'updateGeoLocation');
```

The code is:

```
var googleMapsModel = Backbone.Model.extend ({


    //Init map according to the window height
    initialize: function () {
        _.bindAll(this , 'updateGeoLocation');
        this.set('currentLocation', new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644));
        $("#map-content").height(this.getRealContentHeight());
        var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 15,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),
            mapOptions);
        this.updateGeoLocation();
    },
    //Update geo location and place marker on the map
    updateGeoLocation: function () {
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
                lat = position.coords.latitude;
                long = position.coords.longitude;
                console.log (lat);
                console.log((long));
                currentLocation = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,long);
                map.setCenter(currentLocation);
                //update marker
                this.updateCurrentLocationMarker(currentLocation);
            }) , function() {
                alert("no Geo Location");
            };
        }
    },
updateCurrentLocationMarker: function (markerLocation) {
        myLocationMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: markerLocation,
            map: map
        });
        this.model.set('currentLocationMarker', myLocationMarker);
    },
```

Any help will be appriciated

Comment: You lost "this" when you call it from `initialize` or in other part of your code ?

Comment: In other parts, The problem is inside the anonymous function inside updateGeoLocation

Comment: It's odd because you are in initialize, so this is the correct model instance, and you call `_.bindAll(this , 'updateGeoLocation');` followed by `this.updateGeoLocation();`. This should work !

Comment: If you try this : `this.updateGeoLocation.apply(this)`, does it works ?

Comment: Oh no, I see now the problem, I'll add an answer !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your `updateGeoLocation` method by that :

```
updateGeoLocation: function () {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(_.bind(function (position) {
            lat = position.coords.latitude;
            long = position.coords.longitude;
            console.log (lat);
            console.log((long));
            currentLocation = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,long);
            map.setCenter(currentLocation);
            //update marker
            this.updateCurrentLocationMarker(currentLocation);
        }, this)) , function() {
            alert("no Geo Location");
        };
    }
},
```

The key here is _.bind, take a look at [the doc](http://underscorejs.org/#bind)